# Models being required more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a relatively large Rails application (198 models) where we have constants defined on some models (ie, magic numbers). These constants are sometimes referenced from other models as part of the class definition.

Contrived example:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   TYPES = [ 1234, 5678 ]
end

class CommissionType < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :employee_type, :inclusion => { :in => Employee::TYPES }
end
```

When the application loads, we get warning messages like:

```
employee.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant TYPES
```

I don't know what's causing this, as it appears the employee.rb file is being loaded twice, and therefore the class is being defined twice. Would this also use twice the amount of memory in Ruby by defining everything twice?

I've checked that models don't explicitly require each other. While I could move these constants to initializers, it still seems that there's something wrong with the models being defined more than once.

Is this cause for concern? Or should I just ignore it and shift the constants to initializers?

This is on Rails 3.0.10

Comment: Change `TYPES` into a method returning an array. Then in the method do `puts 'in TYPES()'` and then return the `TYPES` array. See what happens. I wonder if a method can have a constant-like name though?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just do a

```
:in => Employee.TYPES
```

you may have to make TYPES self.